# when app is unloaded from the memory (iphone, low memory) what happens when local notification arrives

Tags: ios, iphone

in case of low memory on iphone would I lose a coming local notification or would my app be loaded back? Is there a way to know the cause of low memory and control what is unloaded? I don't see any leaks in my app in xcode but that happens periodically in my alarm scheduling app. Thanks, Victor

Answer (score 2):

Local notifications are not triggered by your app, but instead they are scheduled by your app and triggered by iOS.
It doesn't matter if your app has been closed by the OS, the notification will show up anyway.
If the user taps on the notification, then your app will be reopened by iOS.

One way to control what is unloaded in case of memory warning is by implementing `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` in your UIViewController subclasses.

Would be nice if you can run Instruments to diagnose what is taking so much memory in your app.

Comment: Hi Matias, maybe I phrased my question not clear. I am asking what will happen when local notification scheduled (obviously by my app since it is a local notification) comes at the time when my app is unloaded due to low memory, not what happens in general. Regards, Victor

Comment: There is nothing specific to the handling due to the reason you specify. Once you schedule a local notification, your application stops being involved.

Comment: Hi @user612514, I believe I also answered that with "It doesn't matter if your app has been closed by the OS, the notification will show up anyway. If the user taps on the notification, then your app will be reopened by iOS."